# jquery animate elements in different order

Tags: jquery, animation

I have code that animates opacity from 0 to 1 to multiple elements on the page. (7 in total) I need to start each elements animation in a specific order, as follows:
element#3,element#4,element#1, element#6, element#7, element #2, element#5.

(Each element contains 3 sub-elements, that is why in the code i have 22 total elements.  As soon as the first element animation completes, the second animation should starts.

The problem is the timing is off:

```
setTimeout(function(){
var delay = 200;
$('.block-item:lt(22)').each(function(){
    $(this).delay(delay)
    .css({ opacity: 0.0 })
    .animate({
        opacity : 1.0
   },600);
   delay += 300;
});
}, 2000);
```

Comment: It appears your math is wrong.  Each is taking 0.6 seconds to animate, but they will start at 0.2, 0.5, and 0.8.  The third will be 2/3 done when the first finished.  Did you mean `delay += 600`?

Comment: That is exactly I need them to animate.  I need help with cahnging order of animation. Thanks

Comment: Can you post an HTML markup sample? or better yet a fiddle with HTML and JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/BtemL)

You can set delays in an object, and then bind them to the elements in some way.  You could use the element's ID, or as I did, its class.

These are some example delays that are ordered first, third, second.

```
var delays = {
  'first': 200,
  'second':1500,
  'third': 300
}
```

This code takes the first class name on each element and gives the above delays.

```
$('.things div').each(function(key, element){
    var className = element.className.split(' ')[0];

    $(this).delay(delays[className] || 500)
    .css({ opacity: 0.0 })
    .animate({
        opacity : 1.0
   },600);
});
```

Your elements just need to have a class linked to the `delays` object.

```
<div class="first">...</div>
<div class="second">...</div>
<div class="third">...</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but not exactly, each of those divs with classes "first", "second" etc, has 3 subitems(3 other divs), that also should have short delay--they should not animate at the same time.

Comment: So, give them classes, and call `$(element).each()` with the same code.  Pass a different object with different classes, or put it all in one.  Just set the delays absolutely, or `after` the first animation finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive function and call it from the callback when the animation finishes.  Create an array of the element ids in the order you want them animated. Call your animation function and animate the first item in the array.  When the animation finishes, remove the item you just finished animating from the array.  Then check and if there are still items in the array, recursively call the animation function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // set up your array
    var order = ['block-item-2','block-item-4','block-item-3','block-item-1','block-item-5'];
    // create your function 
    function anim() {
        var id = '#' + order[0];
        // animate the first item in the array
        $(id).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 600, function() {
            // in the callback remove the item you just animated
            order.shift();
            // if there are still items, call anim() again
            if(order.length) anim();
        });
    }
    // Initial call of anim to kick things off
    anim();
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/znSBh/5/